# Can IAM user be assumed from IAM Role within the same account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

We have an IAM user and an IAM Role in account A. The IAM user can access S3 bucket in account B but IAM role can't access it.

We want to access S3 bucket in account B with IAM role (We don't own account B hence don't want to bother the owner of account B)

Can we make IAM role to assume the IAM user within the same account A, and then access the S3 bucket in account B.

Comment: Depends. How exactly ACC B granted access? Does it do it by allowing entire Acc A to access the bucket, or just this one specific user?

Comment: No. But please tell us your _actual_ goal and we can try to help. For example, it seems like you might be wanting to copy data between Amazon S3 buckets that belong to different AWS Accounts? Tell us more!

Comment: In case it's not clear, you assume IAM roles, not IAM users.

Comment: Double check that the IAM role has sufficient permissions to read from the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

No, an IAM role cannot assume an IAM user. IAM users cannot be assumed. The only way to use the IAM user is to use the IAM user's credentials, either the API Key/Secret or the username/password via the console.

The best solution will be to have account B update the bucket policy to trust the account A root instead of a specific IAM user.